# How to create a new table in Entity Framwowrk Core for code-first approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

Initially I started with the below code

```
public class ShareMyBlogPostContext : DbContext
{
   public ShareMyBlogPostContext(DbContextOptions<ShareMyBlogPostContext> options):base(options)
   {
   }

   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And I ran the below commands to create the database table and migrations:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialDb
dotnet ef database update
```

But after some time, I realized that I need to  have a new entity and I updated my `DbContext` class as below:

```
public class ShareMyBlogPostContext : DbContext
{
   public ShareMyBlogPostContext(DbContextOptions<ShareMyBlogPostContext> options) : base(options)
   { }

   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

Since I was just starting out the project and there was not much data in `Users` table, it was not a big task for me to delete the already existing `Users` table from the database and `Migrations` folder from my project, and re-executing the above commands. This way I was able to create a new database table named `Blogs`.

But how to create a new database table of the newly added entity in the `DbContext` without removing the existing tables and migrations? As this would not be the scenario every time.

Answer (score 0):

hi please type this command

```
dotnet ef migrations add AddBlogs
dotnet ef database update
```

for more please visit this [Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

also if you want to keep your table you must be change migration.cs files manual to add your tables and fields and just run this command

```
dotnet ef database update
```

Answer (score 0):

EF always looks inside `DbContext` derived class (`ShareMyBlogPostContext` in your case)
to detect changes. Sometimes you may not add separate `DbSet` instance for a newely created class, never mind, if you make a relationship between this newly created class and one of `DbSet` classes, the required tables will be appeared **just after you request it**. Every thing in EF codefirst is *fully-managed* and nothing will happen unless you run `migrations add migrationName` (.net CLI command) in order to generate script for current changes. **Based on your configuration**, there may no migration to be applied unless you request it by `database update`. In this way, you may have multiple migrations, the command Updates the database schema based on the **last migration snapshot**.

Dealing with database changes is a critical parts of any project. So, please read [EF document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) before.